# Google Cloud Platform: Speech to Text Conversion of Large Media Files

Tags: google-cloud-platform, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech

I'm trying to extract text from mp4 media file downloaded from youtube. As I'm using google cloud platform so thought to give a try to google cloud speech.

After all the installations and configurations, I copied the following code snippet to get start with:

```
with io.open(file_name, 'rb') as audio_file:
    content = audio_file.read()
    audio = types.RecognitionAudio(content=content)

config = types.RecognitionConfig(encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16, sample_rate_hertz=16000, language_code='en-US')   

response = client.long_running_recognize(config, audio)
```

But I got the following error regarding file size:

> InvalidArgument: 400 Inline audio exceeds duration limit. Please use a
>   GCS URI.

Then I read that I should use streams for large media files. So, I tried the following code snippet:

```
with io.open(file_name, 'rb') as audio_file:
    content = audio_file.read()

#In practice, stream should be a generator yielding chunks of audio data.

stream = [content]
requests = (types.StreamingRecognizeRequest(audio_content=chunk)for chunk in stream)

config = types.RecognitionConfig(encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,sample_rate_hertz=16000,language_code='en-US')

streaming_config = types.StreamingRecognitionConfig(config=config)

responses = client.streaming_recognize(streaming_config, requests)
```

But still I got the following error:

> InvalidArgument: 400 Invalid audio content: too long.

So, can anyone please suggest an approach to transcribe an mp4 file and extract text. I don't have any complex requirement of very large media file. Media file can be 10-15 mins long maximum. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error message means that the file is too big and you need to first copy the media file to Google Cloud Storage and then specify a Cloud Storage URI such as gs://bucket/path/mediafile.

The key to using a Cloud Storage URI is:

> RecognitionAudio audio =
>   RecognitionAudio.newBuilder().setUri(gcsUri).build();

The following code will show you how to specify a GCS URI for input. Google has a [complete example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/cloud-client/src/main/java/com/example/speech/Recognize.java) on github.

```
  public static void syncRecognizeGcs(String gcsUri) throws Exception {
    // Instantiates a client with GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
    try (SpeechClient speech = SpeechClient.create()) {
      // Builds the request for remote FLAC file
      RecognitionConfig config =
          RecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
              .setEncoding(AudioEncoding.FLAC)
              .setLanguageCode("en-US")
              .setSampleRateHertz(16000)
              .build();
      RecognitionAudio audio = RecognitionAudio.newBuilder().setUri(gcsUri).build();

      // Use blocking call for getting audio transcript
      RecognizeResponse response = speech.recognize(config, audio);
      List<SpeechRecognitionResult> results = response.getResultsList();

      for (SpeechRecognitionResult result : results) {
        // There can be several alternative transcripts for a given chunk of speech. Just use the
        // first (most likely) one here.
        SpeechRecognitionAlternative alternative = result.getAlternativesList().get(0);
        System.out.printf("Transcription: %s%n", alternative.getTranscript());
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you please share an example or sample code snipet?

Comment: Updated my answer to include code and a reference link. This is the code that I used to get started.

Comment: I'm working in python, but got an idea and will give it a try!

Comment: please share if you have any example implemented in python. I'm following the one given on official website but struggling with reading video file placed on google storage.

Comment: @JohnHanley is there any other option except the google storage? as it is paid. so it costs for the storage as well read and write as well

Comment: @Nitin - Please create a new question.

Comment: @JohnHanley I have created a new question please refer link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57586169/google-cloud-platform-speech-to-text-gives-unhandledpromiserejectionwarning-er

Comment: @Nitin the question is not accessable.

Comment: Can I specify any other URL instead of gs://bucket/path/mediafile?

Comment: @AqeelAbbas - Create a new question and provide details in your post.